# Motor not working via transistor

Tags: motor, netduino, 5v

I have a very simple circuit as follows

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9eS3I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

when the motor is connected in this fashion, the netduino activates the transistor, but nothing happens. If i swap the motor with an LED, the LED does light up, so that incidates that the motor isnt getting enough power...

So i connect the motor direct to power and gnd, and it spins. Does this mean that the transistor is drawing so much current that it is stopping the motor working?

Comment: The diode is backwards. As it is connected currently, when the transistor is on, the diode is a short-circuit.

Comment: Also, I don't see why the 100ohm resistor is there - it would be better if it were connected between netduino and base of the transistor.

Comment: Motor details? What is R1 supposed to be doing?

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault in the schematic, it is the correct way round on the breadboard

Comment: Updated schematic. Removed unnessecary resistor, and even tried replacing the transistor with a darlinton pair, but in this case there was even less power, as a LED shows even less brightness in place of the motor.

Comment: What current does the motor require?

Comment: I can't find many details on the motor, it runs on 3 to 6V, and the transistor is this  http://www.maplin.co.uk/low-power-lf-npn-transistor-to92h-case-224216#specification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the netduino IO to be 3V3 and this means the emitter of the transistor can never be higher than about 2.7V with any load connected. This is realistically the problem you have - the motor is only receiving about half of the 5V it needs and is therefore stalling. The led works because it only needs a couple of volts (more than likely).

You need to have the motor and diode (same way round as drawing shows) from the collector up to +5V. The emitter needs grounding and the input to the base (from the netduino) goes via a 1k resistor.

[image]

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I have swapped the motor and diode to the collector side of the transistor, but am still not seeing the motor move. Could it just be that the output from the netduino IO is not enough?

Comment: Have you used a 1kohm resistor in the base? As a quick test if you disconnect the resistor from the IO pin and link that point up to +5V does the motor turn? If yes, then maybe you haven't programmed the IO pin correctly. If no then try linking that point up to +3V3 - this should still turn the motor - if not then try lowering the 1kohm to 220 ohm - let me know Wayneio

Comment: Yeah, 1k. I added an LED in series, after the emitter to ensure the circuit was working. The transistor's base pin then was connected the the +5v, and the LED lit up(so bright nearly blew it) but the motor still did not turn. I tried the motor again to just 5v and gnd and it worked, so there must be a problem with either the transistor or netduino IO

Comment: You need to take out the LED because it will reduce the drive to the motor by 2V or maybe more. Try again without the LED Wayneio

Comment: I should have clarified, i just used the led to test the circuit, but did take it out again

Comment: OK try 100 ohms in the base but check that the transistor can take 30mA throught the base - a lot can but it's worth a check

Comment: I don't think the 2N3904 can take the base current BTW. Also it's collector current rating is small - what is your motor rated it from a 5V supply? I think you'll need a more powerful transistor or a FET

Comment: The motor is a 4-6V one, and the transistor is the same as in this circuit, which appears to work http://www.oomlout.com/oom.php/products/nedx/ncir-03

Comment: The circuit (ignoring values) is exactly what i proposed in my answer - that's point 1. Point 2 is that this new circuit uses a more powerful transistor than the one in your circuit. Point 3 - why are you now claiming your circuit uses a P2N222A transistor when clearly your circuit diagram, in your question says, 2N3904. Is your motor the same as the one shown in the circuit or is this different? What is its power rating? What is its current rating from a 5V supply? You have to help us help you and this isn't happening at the moment

Comment: You were right before that the transistor wasn't powerfull enough, I swapped it out and with the other change of putting the motor collector-side, I am up and running. Thanks for you're help

Comment: That's great @wayneio

Answer (score 2):

Your high-side switch (transistor) is functioning as an emitter-follower, which (among other things) means that the emitter voltage can never be higher than 0.7 V *less* than the voltage coming out of the Netduino — or 1.4 V less in the case of the Darlington pair.

If the microprocessor on the Netduino is operating at 3.3V, this means that you're only delivering 2.6 V (or 1.9 V with the Darlington) to the motor.

A better configuration would be to put the transistor on the low side of the motor, or said a different way, put the motor between the 5V supply and the collector of the transistor.